# Layout issue android

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, responsive-design

I'm developing an application in android studio. I wanna make my app responsive for  different devices, I have an issue with the layout

First i have three controls a EditText, TextField, Spinner, The spinner load the data when the fragment is created. All of them are in a GridLayout with the following code:

```
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:layout_margin="2sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHeight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Height"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp" />

        <EditText
            android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_margin="2sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_width="120sp"/>


        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_margin="2sp"
          />

    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I center the controls without affect the responsive design, I wanna something like this:
[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjZgj.png)

The problem that i have is the spinner gets more space than the other two controls, it's the same when I change the orientation of the phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use grid layout? I think it would be better to use a `linearLayout` (`layout_width = match_parent` and `layout_height = 200dp`) with horizontal orientation, then you specify it's `weighSum` to 3, and you put those views inside this `linearLayout`, with `layout_width = 0`, `layout_weight = 1` and `gravity = center`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works. I am new to android can you recommend any book or blog to accelerate my learning?

Answer (score 0):

Just specify `android:layout_width="80dp"` etc or just use

```
android:layout_weight=0.3
android:layout_weight=0.3
android:layout_weight=0.4
```

for the views